# Inserting values into a map

Tags: c++

```
  typedef map <int, string> MAP_INT_STRING;

  MAP_INT_STRING mapIntToString;
  mapIntToString.insert (MAP_INT_STRING::value_type (3, “Three”));
```

I have only found examples where the values are inserted into the map through the source code.  I would like to know how to allow a user do so as the program is running.  I image this would involve some sort of for loop, but I am not certain how to set it up.

Comment: give them a copy of your source code :)

Comment: Can you clarify your question, perhaps with a use case or a scenario?  How does the user interact with your system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now, speaking seriously. first you need to take values from users and then to insert them into your map. something like this:

```
std::map<int, std::string> m;
while (true) {
    std::cout << "please give me an int\n";
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    std::cout << "now gimme some string\n";
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(i, s));
    std::cout << "continue? (y/n)";
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    if (c != 'y')
        break;
}
```

Comment: What if I enter "abc" when you ask for an int?

Comment: @Fred: tnx, I forgot to mention: it's not production-ready solution for sure. you still need to implement error handling

Answer (score 3):

```
int main() {
  using namespace std;
  map<int, string> m;
  cout << "Enter a number and a word: ";
  int n;
  string s;
  if (!(cin >> n >> s)) {
    cout << "Input error.\n";
  }
  else {
    m[n] = s;
    // Or: m.insert(make_pair(n, s));
  }
  return 0;
}
```